# ng repeat hybrid behaviour when is object and list of object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

At first i have a XML file and i transform this to JSON file. For some reason one XML element in json is object, and more than one elements in XML is array of objects in json.
For example i have this JSON

```
        $scope.Settings = {
            Area: [{
                Category: {
                   Caption: '1'
                }
            }, {
                Category: [{
                   Caption: '2'
                 },{
                   Caption: '3'
                 } ]
            }]
        }
```

I need in my html to have ng-repeat for each category. The problem is that 'Category' sometimes is array of object, sometimes is object. Can somehow to create a hybric behaviour for ng-repeat?

Comment: You would be better standardizing your source data, wrapping single object in an array.

Comment: yeaah..you believe that i didn't try that? Because i use 3rd part of libraries a cannot do this

Comment: I dont know, you never said if you tried that, nor did you specify where you get that data from, so a perfectly valid suggestion with the info you provided. There will a point when the data comes from your third party source and into your model, hopefully through a service. You can intercept it and transform it there,

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try by create data preparation method in controller or even dedicated service, so once you receive this data e.g from REST service, the template will get the same format, for example category be always array, if it returns object make a one element array for example, in that way is better to handle it from the template